# Jointly normal and correlated normal random variables

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

Is is true that if two normal random variables are correlated, then they are jointly normally distributed? I am not sure how to prove or disprove it.

Comment: A large collection of pairs of normal random variables that are _not_ jointly normal can be found in _[this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/30205/6633)_ on stats.SE. My contribution to the collection was $$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases}
2f_X(x)f_Y(y), & \text{if}~ x \geq 0, y \geq 0, \text{or}~ x < 0, y < 0,\\
0,& \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$ where $X$ and $Y$ are _zero-mean_ normal random variables with the same variance. It should be obvious that $X$ and $Y$ are positively correlated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly not true.  Suppose $X\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ and
$$
Y = \begin{cases} \phantom{-}X & \text{if } -c<X<c, \\ -X & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}
$$
Then $Y\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$. The correlation between $X$ and $Y$ depends on $c$, and for one special value of $c$ it is $0$, and for all others it is not.

(That it is not normally distributed can be seen by observing that its support is constrained to the two lines $y=\pm x$.  That $Y$ is normally distributed is a fairly routine exercise.)

Answer (score 1):

For better understanding I would like the to rephrase the question. 
If  two random variables have   normal marginal densities  are they  jointly  normally distributed? 
The answer is NO. This enlightening counterexample appears in the famous book
"Counterexamples in Probability and Statistics" by Joseph Romano and Andrew Spiegel.

Let $$g(x,y)=(1/2\pi)\exp\left\{\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}\right\} $$
This is the bivariate Gaussian with mean vector $0$ and var-cov the  identity matrix.

Take $$f(x,y)=2g(x,y)\;\text{if}\; xy\geq 0$$
$$f(x,y)=0\;\text{if not}$$

One can verify that $f$ is bivariate density, clearly non-normal, of two correlated variables which are marginally normally distributed.

Answer (score 0):

No, for an extreme example, take $X \sim N(0, 1)$, and consider the random vector $(X, -X)$, clearly, $X$ and $-X$ are (perfectly) correlated while they are not jointly normally distributed. A simple way to verify this is 
by noting $X + (-X) \equiv 0$ is not normally distributed. On the other
hand, given $(X, Y)$ are jointly normal, then $X + Y$ must also be normally distributed. Contradiction.

Comment: But $X$ and $-X$ _are_ jointly normally distributed! $\qquad$

Comment: If this answer were correct, then one would have to say that every joint normal distribution in which the variance is a singular matrix is not a joint normal distribution.  Consider the residuals in simple linear regression. You have $Y_i = \alpha_0+\beta_0 x_i+\varepsilon_i$ and $\varepsilon_i,\  i=1,\ldots,n$ are i.i.d. $N(0,\sigma^2)$ are the _errors_, not to be confused with the _residuals_ $\widehat\varepsilon_i$.  The residuals necessarily satisfy $\sum_i \widehat\varepsilon_i=0$ and $\sum_i \widehat\varepsilon_i x_i = 0$, so their distribution is a singular normal distribution. $\qquad$

Comment: I personally do not consider a degenerated normal distribution as a joint normal distribution.

Comment: One can exhibit examples of joint distributions with correlated normally distributed components that are much farther from the family of normal distributions with non-singular variances than is this example that is right on the boundary. $\qquad$

Comment: In light of your personal belief about degenerate normal distributions, you might want to read the extensive discussion in the comments that follow _[this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/30160/6633)_ on stats.SE. The point that @MichaelHardy made in his first comment is also part of the discussion.